# Create an ArrayList to store HashSet in Java

Tags: java, hashset

I have an array of nodes, which is 4000 elements large. During my traversal algorithm, each node will meet other node. I want to create a `HashSet` to store each node it meets on the way.
Each node should has their own `HashSet`.

Does Java have a construct like this?

```
<Hashset<Node>>[] res = new Hashset<Node>[4000];
```

Comment: The answer provided and the question asked no longer agree with each other. If you have a separate question to ask, create a new question to ask it with.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [A generic type parameter may itself be generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5), and thus the following is valid:

```
ArrayList<HashSet<Node>> res=new  ArrayList<HashSet<Node>>();
```

Note capitalization in the name of `java.util.HashSet`.

Comment: what about array of hashset. because all the node should has this hashset. arraylist is dynamic. The index may not point to the node index.

Comment: @user3382017 I do not understand what you are saying in that comment, as it does not make sense.

Comment: i mean Hashset<Node>[] possible? when i want to check node[i]'s hashset, Hashset<Node>[i] is what i need.

Comment: @user3382017 Yes, parametrized types can be used in arrays. However, you *must* spell `HashSet` correctly, with the S capital.

Comment: no it works wrong. Cannot create a generic array of HashSet<Node>

Comment: @user3382017 That is because arrays are covariant and due to type erasure. What is wrong with `ArrayList` as the answer gives?